# ASP.Net core 2 Discord Authentication OAUTH

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

i am trying to integrate discord login into my web application using this library: https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.OAuth2

I am adding everything how i should as far as i am aware, i can make it all the way to the discord link, then i get given this screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYupF.png

this is the code i am using:

```
        services.AddAuthentication().AddDiscord(x =>
        {
            x.AppId = "";
            x.AppSecret = "";
        });
```

this is the string that is generated using the library:

```
https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={clientId}&scope=identify&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44347%2Fsignin-discord&state=CfDJ8PAtggBypNpIqEV5dHP8jFixucPeC53KpJviz6NT3zjCoYn2t8iv-L54S7g6Lu5zeu_K_fJyiq1lLqSUl3pYdsCgSR2zdMBA94rQei3EP207mfPQNxX0WUWOJiCsznpYz-8_wq058ZQb6yUKYzC1ZYJu1LMTA8208iC8hN7j8xkWeBQyEVVPXTfF2bT3__zZyk74_h3tQe0JjQHQ3KZUXpWECreTWOgLrDmdw2ipRYJThwPf8kok0L-LQK2K4b3vMQo6KlCoQz-rWDSABRw5iOE
```

Any help would be appreciated as i need to try and get this working.

Kind Regards,

Corey

Comment: `{clientId}` doesn't look right in that request URL.

Comment: This is directly from discord api site: https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=157730590492196864&scope=identify%20guilds.join&state=15773059ghq9183habn&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fnicememe.website

Answer (score 1):

Your `{clientId}` slug should be replaced with the `DiscordOptions.AppId` when the redirect happens. If it's not there's a bug in the module.